# Can't Call Odoo Api From Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, odoo

I have created an API in Odoo using Controller. The auth type is public, so no authentication is required to access this API. When I call this API in Postman or any browser, I have no problem. But when I access this API in Flutter I got an error.

This is the Flutter code

```
var response = await Dio().get('https://my-odoo-domain.com/api/sales');
print(response);
```

And this is the error message

```
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error.
Source stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 910:28       get current
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 473:35                                   fetch
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 472:31                                   fetch
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 468:12                                   request
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 438:33                                   request
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 55:12                                    get
packages/flutter_baru/screens/home_provider.dart 42:32                   fetchRoomMappings
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/flutter_baru/screens/home_provider.dart 18:33                   fetchRoomMappings
packages/flutter_baru/screens/home_provider.dart 14:11                   setup
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/flutter_baru/screens/home_provider.dart 12:21                   setup
packages/flutter_baru/screens/home_screen.dart 13:12                     setup
packages/flutter_baru/base/base_stateful.dart 19:14                      <fn>
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1144:15                      [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1089:9                       handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 862:7                        <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19  internalCallback

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at http://localhost:65437/packages/dio/src/interceptors/log.dart.lib.js:1004:21
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:40445:59)
    at _FutureListener.catchError.handleError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35374:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35947:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35973:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35823:23)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35279:36)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.completeError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35203:29)
    at onError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35043:49)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:40445:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35374:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35947:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35973:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35823:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:35859:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:65437/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I got this error when I run on **Web** platform, but when I run on **Mobile** & **Desktop** platform I got no error. I think the problem is security or something like CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the CORS. I need to enable the CORS by passing CORS parameter in the end point

```
@http.route('/my/route', auth='public' ,cors='*')  
def my_route(self):
```